# Is there a more elegant way to add attributes to Node?

Tags: scala

I have a NodeSeq of nodes with a lot of unknown attributes. The NodeSeq has to be validated, and recreated, with errors (if encountered) added as an attributes in the nodes.

The solution bellow works,but I was wondering if there is more elegant way to achive my goal?

```
def validateErrors (nodes:NodeSeq):NodeSeq={

 var newNodes = new Queue[Node]()
   nodes.foreach ( n => {
     var error:Boolean = false
     var errorMessage:String = ""
     //...do many complex validations
     // and get the error status code and error message
     if (error)
       newNodes += AddError(n,errorMessage)
     else
       newNodes +=n       
   })
   newNodes
}

private def AddError (node:Node, message:String ):Node= node match {  
    case elem : Elem => elem % Attribute(None, "color", Text("red"), Null)  %  Attribute(None, "message", Text(message ), Null) //and many more
    case other => other   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `error` flag you could bmake errorMessage an `Option[String]` and the whole error message creating part a method.

You also could change the addError method to handle the case of no error as well using pattern matching:

```
private def AddError (node:Node, message:Option[String] ):Node= (node, message) match {  
    case (elem : Elem, Some(m) => elem % Attribute(None, "color", Text("red"), Null)  %  Attribute(None, "message", Text(m), Null) //and many more
    case (other,_) => other   
}
```

Note: typed this without scala compilers so probably won't compile, but I hope the idea gets clear.

Comment: I think you want `case _ => node` for the default case, otherwise the case returns a tuple instead of a Node.

Comment: Thanks, I will switch to Option.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might help would be to declare `newNodes` as a `val` instead of a `var` and use `map` or `for` instead of `foreach` to iterate over `nodes` and build the new value. Changing the other `var` declarations to use `val` instead would be good too. Using `Option[String]` for the message (as suggested in Jens Schauder's answer) for the error message eliminates the need for a flag.

```
val nodes = for (n <- nodes) yield {
  val errorMsg: Option[String] = {
    //...do many complex validations
    // and get the error status code and error message
  }
  errorMsg match {
    case Some(msg) => AddError(n, msg)
    case None => n
  }
}
```

Using a `foldLeft` (i.e. `/:`) to add all the attributes might simplify `AddError` too:

```
private def AddError(node: Node, message: String ): Node = node match {  
  case elem: Elem => {
    val attrs = List("color"->Text("red"), "message"->Text(message) /* , ... */)
    (elem /: attrs) { (acc, x) => acc % Attribute(None, x._1, x._2, Null) }
  }
  case _ => node
}
```

You might also want to think about using `case object`s like an `enum` for your Attribute fields:

```
Attribute(None, AttColor, "red", Null)
Attribute(None, AttMsg, Text(message), Null)
```

Case classes might be even better (although you might have to add more cases if `Text` is used in more than one way):

```
Attribute(None, Color("red"), Null)
Attribute(None, MsgText(message), Null)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to convert the vars to vals, and will use the Option as errorMsg